# Generating test cases in TFS(MTM) using Specflow feature file

Tags: tfs, workflow, bdd, specflow

I'm very new to Specflow and working on evaluating it. I was able to write scenario, step definition, and execute the test. But now I'm stuck on integrating the feature file to TFS.

I want to know if there is a way to integrate Specflow feature file to TFS(MTM)

Following is the workflow I want to accomplish :

1. A feature file is created with multiple scenario
2. If the feature file is checked in, scenarios are automatically generated in TFS with corresponding area (maybe using tags?)

or I would appreciate if you could share any other integration suggestions you may have.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related: http://gasparnagy.com/2016/02/integrating-specflow-with-microsoft-test-manager-mtm/

Answer (score 0):

for export scenario can be used TFS API

example - Create work item in Team Project (TFS) using c# code
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ff5415e-0ef2-4c65-b0b7-a109187adf51/create-work-item-in-team-project-tfs-using-c-code?forum=tfsgeneral